web3.py Increase the amount of gas to make the transaction faster in the blockchain
My goal is to have my transaction included in the blockchain as soon as possible.
This code, includes the transaction in the blockchain in 5-7 seconds in eth and polygon.
tx = {
    'from': w3.wallet_address,
    'chainId': tx_data['chain'],
    'value': int(tx_data['value']),
}

priority_fee = gas_price * priority_fee_multiplier
max_fee_per_gas = gas_price * max_fee_multiplier

gas_price, nonce, balance, base_fee, estimate_gas = await asyncio.gather(*[
    w3.get_gas_price(),
    w3.get_nonce(),
    w3.get_balance(),
    w3.get_base_fee(),
    func_order.estimate_gas(tx),
])

tx['maxFeePerGas'] = int(max_fee_per_gas)
tx['maxPriorityFeePerGas'] = int(priority_fee)
tx['gas'] = int(estimate_gas * increase_gas)
tx['nonce'] = nonce

maxFeePerGas, maxPriorityFeePerGas - I pay more gas to speed up the transaction, but still the transactions are not inserted into the blocks fast enough for me.
There is not enough information on the Internet on this issue, so I rely on you)
I've seen transactions on scans that are instantly included in the blockchain, but I can't achieve this result, so I'd be grateful for any information

This code, includes the transaction in the blockchain in 5-7 seconds in eth and polygon.

Average block time in ethereum is 12s . Meaning it takes 12s going from block N to block N+1 . You have to wait for next block  to be validated It can't go faster than that .
